# Copy files from multiple folders into one

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have the following folder structure:

```
>Folder1
  >>date1
    >>>Empty
       1.jpg
       2.jpg
    >>>Occupied
       x.jpg
       y.jpg
  >>date2
    >>>Empty
       1.jpg
       2.jpg
    >>>Occupied
       x.jpg
       y.jpg
```

I need to copy all the files

- in the Empty folders to another single folder
- in the Occupied folders to another single folder

I tried `$ cp Folder1/**/Empty/*.jpg ~/destination_folder/` but it fails giving me the error: "Argument list too long". How do I do this?

Comment: You are going to move files with the same name (1.jpg, for instance) to the same folder. How do you want the conflict of the same name to be resolved?

Comment: actually I just checked and they don't have the same name, I just wrote it as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find Folder1 -wholename '*Empty*.jpg' -exec cp -v {} ~/destination_folder +
```

The `+` at the end of the `-exec` option will call `cp` as many times as needed to avoid the *Argument list too long* error but as less as possible. Meaning it will call `cp` always with the maximum number of arguments.

If your `find` should not support the `+` syntax, you can still use:

```
find Folder1 -wholename '*Empty*.jpg' -exec cp -v {} ~/destination_folder \;
```

which will call `cp` once per source file. While this will still work, it takes a bit more time.